# Django REST Framework - get related objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have these models where one book can have many contents in different languages:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class BookContent(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    language = models.TextField()
```

**--------------------Update--------------------**

How should i fetch Book and its related BookContent such that the result JSON looks like the following?

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "d3e5185a-1b7b-427c-bbe3-030bfa2e3bce",
            "title": "My Book Title",            
            "book_content": [
                {
                    "id": "0fea8027-3ecf-4571-a95f-5a09a93408ec",
                    "content": "hello content 1",
                    "language": "english"
                },
                {
                    "id": "0fea8027-3ecf-4571-a95f-5a09a93408ed",
                    "content": "你好",
                    "language": "chinese"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**models.py**
In BookContent, add **related_name** to foreignKey book

```
class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class BookContent(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='content')
    content = models.TextField()
    language = models.TextField()
```

**serializers.py**
Refer [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) for more info

```
class BookContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BookContent
        fields = ('id', 'content', 'language')

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content = BookContentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'content')
```

Result:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "d3e5185a-1b7b-427c-bbe3-030bfa2e3bce",
            "title": "My Book Title",            
            "book_content": [
                {
                    "id": "0fea8027-3ecf-4571-a95f-5a09a93408ec",
                    "content": "hello content 1",
                    "language": "english"
                },
                {
                    "id": "0fea8027-3ecf-4571-a95f-5a09a93408ed",
                    "content": "你好",
                    "language": "chinese"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to write a query for that like

[take a look at doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/) for reference

```js
query = BookContent.objects.filter(book=book_id)# this will give 
you a queryset with all the book content records with that particular book_id
```

Comment: thank you. but how do i fetch with Book object instead?

Comment: To get one single object you have use get() eg. Book.objects.get(id=book_id)